# Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code running in WSL2 don't follow VS Code color theme

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, wsl-2

I know this may seem petty, but I'm struggling to fix an issue when I open a .ipynb in vscode running wsl2 as the remote. The issue is that the color/formatting doesn't seem to follow the VS Code theme.

Here is a screen shot as an example:

[image: jupyter notebook with a dark color scheme]

VS Code is running `Solarized Dark` as the color theme, but the ipynb is following a completely different dark theme. While it may seem like a silly thing (because otherwise the jupyter notebook is working as expected) the differences in themes make the code hard to read at times, and is a little jarring. It makes me rather work in a normal notebook, and that is the problem, because I'd really like to contain my work inside the IDE if possible.

Below you will see the only setting I could find related to this. When checked, the notebook "ignores" the VS code theme and turns white. When uncheck, it is dark as in the screen shot above.

[image: setting checked to not ignore the vs code theme]

You can see I'm running connected to a WSL2 remote backend. When I run in a normal windows setting, the .ipynb renders as expected, following the VSCode theme. The problem seems to persist exclusively when working in a WSL2 remote.

[image]

Is there any fix for this? I've not found anything yet despite quite a bit of searching.

Comment: Have you tried using other theme colors? For example: Dark+(default dark). And you could refer to and follow the content of this link: [Jupyter Notebook Cell in Dark Theme in WSL not colored](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/646)

Comment: Looks like it’s a straight up bug. Hopefully fixed soon

Comment: Currently, according to the content in the link, it is recommended that you try to use "VS Code-Insiders".